# validation of the formulation only in html

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Hey I have a question how to do validation in html itself. I was looking on the internet but everything that was produced to create new e-mail files and change in them, but I want in html itself:

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<div class="contact_helper">
    <div class="contact_intro">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
    <form action="mail.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Mail" name="email" style="font-family: Roboto">
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" style="font-family: Roboto">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" style="font-family: Roboto">
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Temat" name="subject" style="font-family: Roboto">
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="message"
            style="font-family: Roboto"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There is an attribute for **input fields** called ``pattern``, you can use it for simple validation, but for complex and more edge cases validation you need to do using javascript(for front-end) and on the server-side. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: HTML validations can be set using the type attribute on your input elements. What kind of validations are you exactly looking for?

Comment: You need the `required` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `required` attribute to the input elements:

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<div class="contact_helper">
    <div class="contact_intro">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
    <form action="mail.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Mail" name="email" style="font-family: Roboto" required="required">
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" style="font-family: Roboto" required="required">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" style="font-family: Roboto" required="required">
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Temat" name="subject" style="font-family: Roboto" required="required">
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="message"
            style="font-family: Roboto" required=""></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```